# Reset BINGO game after each round

Tags: javascript, set

Making a bingo game. Got everything to work in terms of getting random numbers that don't repeat and getting them to show. I've also got the set up to be added back to the original array for the next round. The last thing I need help with is resetting the game without refreshing the entire page so that the numbers previously called go away and ONLY the next round of numbers called is displayed.

Basically, I tried the Set.clear() method both before and after the numbers called and displayed, but it still shows the numbers that were previously called in addition to the new numbers. I then tried to add it to the random number generator function to see if it would clear the set before the function was ran again, but still same result. I've also tried using Set.delete() after iterating all the values in the set, but that also displayed the results from every round.

```js
let numbers = new Set()
  .add("B1")
  .add("B2")
  .add("B3")
  .add("B4")
  .add("B5")
  .add("B6")
  .add("B7")
  .add("B8")
  .add("B9")
  .add("B10");

let called = Array.from(numbers);
let display = new Set();

function getRandomNum() {

  function rando() {
    for (let i = 0; i < called.length; i++) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * called.length);
      const number = called[i];
      called[i] = called[j];
      called[j] = number;

      if (number) {
        called.splice(j, 1);
      }

      if (called.length < 0) {
        return;
      } else {
        return number;
      }
    }

  }

  if (called.length === 0) {
    index = "No More Numbers";
  } else {
    index = rando();
    display.add(index);
  }
  document.getElementById('bingo').innerHTML = index;

}

function show() {
  function showMe() {
    for (let n of display) {

      document.getElementById('reveal').innerHTML += "<br/>" + n + "<br/>";
      called.push(n);
    }
  }
  showMe();
  display.clear();
}
```

```html
<div id="bingo">
</div>

<div id="button">
  <button onclick="getRandomNum()">Random Number</button>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<div id="reveal">
  <button onclick="show()">Numbers Called</button>
</div>
```

All I'm looking to do is "wipe the slate clean" of the numbers called, so to speak, after calling BINGO and displaying the called numbers so that another round of Bingo can be executed without having to refresh the entire web page.

Comment: 1. declare the variables without setting them 2. set them inside an `init()` function. 3. when a new game is supposed to start, call `init()` again

Comment: instead of appending the numbers displayed direct to `#reveal` add another container inside `#reveal` and append the numbers to this container, then when round ends, select this container and do `container.innerHTML = ""` to clear it, so it will be empty

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/q270mjc3/

Answer (score 0):

The most solution, for me, was changing the whole thing.

Instead of getting random numbers, try to create an array, and instead of random, try to use the shuffle function on the array of all numbers you want.

Also, you may use a seed for that.

That is the most effective solution I found.